# Differential Equations (ODE). Book.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I read "Ordinal Differential Equations" by V.I. Arnold (in russian). In 1st lesson he told about differential 1-forms and explained form's ingration. Also he told about monodromy.
In the next lesson he told about attractors:)

Can you suggest me "book for mathematician", please? It means that in the book I can read not only about solving and DE -- I can read about principles, about ideas and theories.

(I want to understand what is holonomy. Thats why I find good book about ODE.)

Thanks.